# .css() won't update background color

Tags: javascript, html

The entirety of the code works but when I copy the code to my friends website the color won't update like it would normally. Not sure why it's not working now.

[https://pastebin.com/jm8s6gzX][1]

```
   function loadPalletes() {
        let colorIndexNum = 0;
        for(let palletes in penguinColors) {
            let colorHex = penguinColors[palletes],
                colorIndex = palletes,
                colorIndexCurrNum = ++colorIndexNum;
            $('#palletes').append(`<div data-id="${colorIndexCurrNum}" class="tinyPallete" style="background: #${colorHex}"></div> `);
        }
        $("#palletes").on("click", function(e) {
            let palletId = $(e.target).attr('data-id'); 
            e.currentTarget.querySelector('.active') ?.classList.remove('active');
            if(e.target.classList.contains('tinyPallete')) {
                e.target.classList.add('active');
            }
            $("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', penguinColorByIndex(palletId, false));
            console.log("color updated?")
        });
    }
 
    function penguinColorByIndex(index, keys) {
        if(keys) {
            return(Object.keys(penguinColors)[--index]);
        }
        return(Object.values(penguinColors)[--index]);
    }
    let penguinColors = { 
        "Blue": "003366",
        "Green": "009900",
        "Pink": "FF3399",
        "Black": "333333",
        "Orange": "FF6600",
        "Yellow": "FFCC00",
        "Dark Purple": "660099",
        "Brown": "996600",
        "Red": "CC0000",
        "Dark Green": "006600",
        "Light Blue": "0099CC",
        "Lime Green": "8AE302",
        "Gray": "93A0A4",
        "Aqua": "02A797",
        "Arctic White": "F0F0D8"
    };
   window.onload = function() {
        loadPalletes();
    }
```

I attached a pastebin of the entire index page.

Comment: Post relevant **code** in the question - check browser console for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

`$("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', penguinColorByIndex(palletId, false));`

And specifically the returned value of `penguinColorByIndex`, which is just the hexvalue (for example, `333333`).

You need to add a hash to make it valid, like:

`$("#penguinDoll").css('background-color', '#' + penguinColorByIndex(palletId, false));`

So you're setting `#333333`, and not `333333`.

Comment: That's weird cause on my original file I didn't have to include the hashtag but that did solve the issue.